# how can I create simple splash around rocks for water?

Tags: edit-mode

I tried this before and had poor results and had to use images as planes for wave splashes on rocks and a boat.  So I was wondering if there is a better way to create splashes of waves around rocks for ocean spray to hide the "flat contact" around the rocks from the ocean modifier.  I used mesh deforms before but that was only for the body of a boat.  I actually would like some proper looking splash water that is not very complicated.  What would I use for this, a particle method? Pointing upward with initial velocity of some sort? Easiest is preferred.
[image: ocean modifier square edge interactions]

Comment: Hello :). You explained it pretty well, but could you also add some images to illustrate?